# What is the purpose of "Don't code sign" value in XCode -> Build Settings -> Code Signing?

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

I found a code signing property "Don't Code Sign" in the XCode -> Build Settings -> Code Signing. When and where we should use this?. What does this mean for a device which is properly added to the developer portal(with proper developer certificate)?.

Comment: You don't need to sign code for the simulator.

Comment: I believe you can also build the app not signed, ship it to someone and then they sign the build app manually.

Comment: for Don't code sign you can test your app only in simulator. for testing in iPhone device you need developer certificate for your device.

Answer (score 3):

The app we built was being delivered to the client unsigned because they then used the local app store provided with the Citrix solution to sign & host the app for their enterprise.

If we signed the app, the Citrix couldn't import it and add a signature of it's own (supposedly... I still find this hard to believe), so the client insisted that the app is NOT signed.

Answer (score -1):

this made way easier for student like me, we need to create iOS app but we didnt want to publish it to App Stores. Apple allow unsigned app to be test on own iOS devices.

Comment: "Apple allow unsigned app to be test on own iOS devices". That's not true. Even developer builds are signed.